# Concatenating fields using VBscript in ArcGIS Field Calculator?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, arcgis-9.3, vbscript

I'm trying to get one column of text to move into another column that already has text.  I DON'T want to replace it, I want the transferring text to be added to the already existing text in a shp file attribute table.

#### Example

```
permit   acct id
123      567
324      456
```

I want to take the "acct id" numbers and bring them into the permit column and have it look like this...

```
permit
123567
324456
```

Comment: Is this in ArcGIS 9.3 ?

Comment: yes it is in 9.3

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to concatenate information from two fields using the `&` operator (see [this link](http://resources.arcgis.com/content/kbase?fa=articleShow&d=31807) for all supported operators) . You can do this from ArcGIS's Field Calculator using `[mycol1] =`:

```
[mycol1] & [mycol2]
```

If you want a space in between the two values:

```
[mycol1] & " " & [mycol2]
```

This only works for **text** type destination fields. If you want something fancier, then you probably need to do some preprocessing in the "Advanced" mode.

Comment: I've tried that and I'm recieving the FC box saying "At least one value did not fit into the specificed text field and had to be truncated. truncated values are flagged with a trailing *

Comment: i clicked the column I wanted... FC ... then I clicked the "township" and the "section (column that I need the numbericals to be transferred)"  [township] & [section] is what it looks like

Comment: Mike, ok..only in text... what can you do if it is Numerical?

Comment: You can only have numbers (no spaces or string characters) in numeric fields.  The rule of thumb I've used is, unless you're going to perform math on the field's values, make it a text field.  Note that if you want to convert from text to numeric or vice-versa, you can use VBA functions to do so (just like in Excel)